# How to position bullet points and static footer contents in css?

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer

I am working on the static footer section of a website in which I want to position bullets and contents in the fixed footer. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56gawbe1/2/embedded/result) of what I have done.

```css
ul.social-network:before {
  content: "• ";
  font-size: 150%;
}

.static-email:before {
  content: "• ";
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row  pb-2">
  <div class="col-md-12 footer-cont" st="">
    <i class="fas fa-phone pr-1"></i>
    <a href="tel:+1234567890" class="pr-3">
      +1 234 456 7890
      </a>
    <span class="static-email">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope pl-3 pr-1"></i>
      <a href="mailto:helloworld@world.com">
      helloworld@world.com
      </a>
      </span>
    <ul class="social-network social-circle">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/" target="_blank" class="icoLinkedin" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in **the CSS so that bullet points and static footer contents are vertically centred**.  At this moment, if we see the screenshot below (copied from the fiddle) **the bullet points and the email are not properly vertically centred, they are up and down.**

[image]

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is really a duplicate of 'Vertical Align Text After Font Icon', though I'm sure this has been answered before. One option is to add 'position: relative;' to those selectors and fine-tune position of the bullet via `top`.

Comment: @joknawe Can you update it in the fiddle ? In that way, it will be easy for me to visualize.

Comment: Yeah @dippas this is a totally different question. The other question doesn't use `:before` at all (or even `:after` for that matter).

Comment: @LincolnBergeson I am wondering if you can me pointer how to solve this question or if you can update the fiddle. In that way, it will be to visualize.

Comment: @user5447339 I've updated the fiddle - though it seemed pretty aligned when I viewed, but this should help you.

Comment: @joknawe Ok thanks, where is fiddle but ?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson added one of the many dupes you can find in here about vertical alignment, (it really doesn't matter if is in a pseudo element or not, the logic is the same)

Comment: @user5447339 it is out of alignment because the font size is 150%. Change it to 100% and it aligns correctly. As @joknawe is saying you can put `position: relative` on the element and bump it up or down a few pixels manually if you like.

Comment: @user5447339 https://jsfiddle.net/56gawbe1/8/

Comment: @dippas The logic is very different between regular & pseudo elements but I agree that the second link is a much better duplicate, and should be more helpful to OP.